# powershell force module version dependency in module

Tags: powershell, module, manifest

I recently discovered [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66002063/unable-to-publish-to-azure-devops-nuget) with the powershellget module that seems to be resolved in the beta versions of that module. When I run powershell, it automatically seems to load the 2.2.5 version of the module but the problem is fixed in the 3.0.0-beta10 module. When I manually delete the 2.2.5 version from my

```
%programfiles%\WindowsPowerShell\modules\PowerShellGet
```

folder and manually load the 3.0.0 version using Import-Module and then the full path to the local module, it loads the version I want. Because my commands are in a module that I want to make publicly available, deleting that folder isn't really viable, so I'm trying to make my module force load that version of the module. I am wondering what the proper way to do this is. Because its a beta module, it doesn't seem to be honored when using

```
#Requires -Modules @{ ModuleName="PowerShellGet"; ModuleVersion="3.0.0" }
```

Inside the function itself and I'm a bit unsure what to do next since PowerShellGet is a pretty core module.

Edit: When I remove both version 2.2.5 and 3.0.0 I get the following error:

```
The script 'Publish-ToPSGallery.ps1' cannot be run because the following modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: PowerShellGet.
At D:\Public\powershell\modules\xanderu.helpers\xanderu.helpers\xanderu.helpers.psm1:43 char:6
+             . $_.FullName
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Publish-ToPSGallery.ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptRequiresMissingModules
```

When I use the command:

```
install-module Powershellget -force  -AllowPrerelease
```

it installs the right version (3.0.0) but I don't know how to set this in the manifest.

Edit 2:
During my testing I think that the problem isn't actually solved with v3.0.0 but my nuget permissions that I overrode did persist until I started a new session.

Edit 3:
I did end up resolving the issue I was dealing with and I the propagate is fixed in beta: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/85

The being said... how can I force the v3.0.0beta inside a module... Still not entirely sure about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to be honored" - does it load the old version instead?

Comment: I edited the OP with the message I get. When I use #requires it just throws the message, but I'm trying to figure out how to make the module manifest pull the required version accordingly via RequiredModules = @() which I believe would make it download the 3.0.0 version automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in the beta build for PowerShellGet:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/85